# How do I center nav links

Tags: html, css, nav

Trying to spread these nav links out evenly and have them centered on the page. I managed to get the ul centered in the middle of the page, but I'm not sure how to center the links.

I'm guessing it's something in the li that I need to change, but not sure what..

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 50%;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you want vertical menu or in horizontal menu `li` might be center

Comment: Do you want all links to be in one row or one colum? Or two columns?

Comment: I want it horizontal, like it currently is. Issue is, the links aren't in the middle of the page. They're off to the left..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flex, you can also add the other things you want too, like list style and background color.
Have a look at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) fam, it'll change your life.

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid` to easily do this. Here's a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q6j3ryft/)

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two column view

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 50%;

  /* add display flex */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

li {
  width:50%; /*if you want in one row then 100%/4 = 25% */
  float: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

**Bonus :** 
Change the `text-decoration` in CSS on `li a` to force it to work

`text-decoration: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav id="nav_tag">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

#nav_tag{
         text-align:center;
         margin-left:{appropriate amount}%;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to change much,  just delete this :

```
li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**please try below css:**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```